# Плагин на отображение контента в папках

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте! Есть ли на wordpress плагин который допустим отображал контент в папках? Например я удалил файл из папки, заменил на новый и новый файл отобразился на сайте. Или возможно такое реализовать без плагинов?

Comment: http://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/ - что-то вроде этого?

Comment: Ну впринципе да, что то типа ftp плагина какого то чтобы пользователи могли скачивать и выглядело для них по красивее).

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-filebase/ - посмотри этот плагин.

Comment: я как понял этот плагин использует свою базу, которая синхронизируется с папкой, т.е произвольную папку он не будет отображать и использовать её ресурсы, а только видит свою базу?